# Yii2: does it have an abstraction for accessing $_REQUEST?

Tags: php, yii2

Does Yii2 have an abstraction for `$_REQUEST`? I don't seem to find it, so maybe there is a reason for not having it?

Maybe I have to figure it out manually by just using `Yii::$app->request->get()` and `Yii::$app->request->post()`?

Comment: request is just a combination of get and post and cookie. and is genrally a bad idea to use

Comment: True, but in my case the security concerns are not an issue at all.

Comment: its still bad practice, so start getting use to good practice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yii1 had it, in Yii2 it's gone.

You could just mimic old behavior with a adapted Request class though:

```
class Request extends \yii\web\Request {
    /**
     * for compatibility with yii1 request->getParam()
     */
    public function getParam($name, $defaultValue = NULL) {
        return isset($_GET[$name]) ? $_GET[$name] : (isset($_POST[$name]) ? $_POST[$name] : $defaultValue);
    }
}
```

You need to override the request application component setting to use your own class then.